# Why isn't my custom directives dropdown firing?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

**What's going on?**

Everything works and populates correctly from what I can tell. The only thing that's misbehaving is the dropdown. For some reason it won't fire and display all of it's submenus/dividers.

***app.directives.js***

```
angular.module('mb.essentials', [])
.directive('mbAttribute', function ($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            mbAttribute: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(scope.mbAttribute)) {
                $log.error(
                    'You must specify at least one attribute, condition pair!\n' +
                    'Eg. mb-attribute="{\'alert-warning\': alert.alertType}"');
            }

            $.each(scope.mbAttribute, function (key, value) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return value;
                },
                function() {
                    if (value) {
                        element.attr(key, '');
                    } else {
                        element.removeAttr(key, '');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
.directive('mbNavbar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '^dropdown',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            brand: '=',
            menus: '=',
            affixed: '=',
            inverse: '=',
            search: '=',
            searchFn: '&',
            navFn: '&'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $sce) {
            $scope.isCollapsed = true;

            $scope.defaults = {
                brand: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>',
                menus: [],
                search: {
                  show: false
                }
            }; // end defaults

            if (angular.isUndefined($attrs.navFn)) {
                $scope.navfn = function (action) {
                    if (angular.isObject(action))
                        $scope.$emit('nav.menu', action);
                    else
                        $scope.$emit('nav.menu', {'action': action});
                }
            };

            if (angular.isUndefined($attrs.searchFn)) {
                $scope.searchFn = function () {
                    $scope.$emit('nav.search.execute');
                }
            };

            $scope.trustedBrand = angular.isDefined($attrs.brand) ? $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.brand) : $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.defaults.brand);
            $scope.hasMenus = function () {
                return angular.isDefined($scope.menus);
            };

            $scope.hasDropdownMenu = function (menu) {
                return (angular.isDefined(menu.menu) && angular.isArray(menu.menu));
            };

            $scope.isDivider = function (item) {
                return (angular.isDefined(item.divider) && angular.equals(item.divider, true));
            }

            $scope.navAction = function (action) {
                $scope.navFn({'action': action});
            };
        },
        template: 
        '<nav class="navbar" ng-class="{\'navbar-inverse\': inverse,\'navbar-default\': !inverse,\'navbar-fixed-top\': affixed == \'top\',\'navbar-fixed-bottom\': affixed == \'bottom\'}" role="navigation">' +
            '<div class="container-fluid">' +
                '<div class="navbar-header">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">' +
                        '<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<a class="navbar-brand" ng-bind-html="trustedBrand"></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div collapse="isCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse">' +
                    '<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-if="hasMenus()">' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="menu in menus" mb-attribute="{\'dropdown\': hasDropdownMenu(menu)}">' +
                            '<a ng-if="!hasDropdownMenu(menu)" ng-click="navAction(menu.action)">{{menu.title}}</a>' +
                            '<a ng-if="hasDropdownMenu(menu)" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>' +
                                '{{menu.title}} <b class="caret"></b>' +
                            '</a>' +
                            '<ul ng-if="hasDropdownMenu(menu)" class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                '<li ng-repeat="item in menu.menu" ng-class="{\'nav-divider\': isDivider(item)}">' +
                                    '<a ng-if="!isDivider(item)" ng-click="navAction(item.action)">{{item.title}}</a>' +
                                '</li>' +
                            '</ul>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '<form ng-if="search.show" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<div class="input-group">' +
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.terms" />' +
                                '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                                    '<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">' +
                                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>' +
                                    '</button>' +
                                '</span>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</form>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</nav>'
    };
});
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I7bbbxEZW1TPv5UYoHDW?p=info)

Comment: This is not what is considered a ***minimal***, verifiable example. Suggest you create a plunker demo

Comment: I created a plunker demo and only kept the directives code snippet. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are all dependencies included for navbar? Seems to have a require for a `dropdown` directive controller but I don't see that directive ..`require: '^dropdown',`

Comment: That directive is part of ui.bootstrap I really only put the require in there in an attempt to get it to work.

Comment: was wondering why it wasn't throwing error...is late and I should have known better.

Comment: 'select' needs a `ng-model` in order to render properly

Comment: What do you mean by select? I'm not using a select for my drop down.

Comment: I figured out a bit more information. When I put the dropdown attribute right into the html rather then using my mbAttribute directive it works correctly. 

It seems that you can't add directives conditionally like I currently am since it requires recompiling the DOM. I'm going to look into an alternative, however if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this elegantly I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

***The Issue***

Basically angular compiles the DOM then the mb-attribute directive adds the dropdown directive. Essentially Angular and UI Bootstrap have no idea the directive even exists.

***The "Solution"***

I put this in quotes because it isn't entirely a solution.

Rather then conditionally checking if the dropdown directive should be added. We just add it to every element, regardless of whether or not its a dropdown menu.

The reason this works in this case is because UI Bootstraps dropdown directive requires it to be paired with a dropdown-toggle as well as a dropdown-menu in order to operate properly.

***angular.directives.js***

```
angular.module('mb.essentials', [])
.directive('mbNavbar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '^dropdown',
        scope: {
            brand: '=',
            menus: '=',
            affixed: '=',
            inverse: '=',
            search: '=',
            searchFn: '&',
            navFn: '&'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $sce) {
            $scope.isCollapsed = true;

            $scope.defaults = {
                brand: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>',
                menus: [],
                search: {
                  show: false
                }
            } // end defaults

            if (angular.isUndefined($attrs.navFn)) {
                $scope.navfn = function (action) {
                    if (angular.isObject(action))
                        $scope.$emit('nav.menu', action);
                    else
                        $scope.$emit('nav.menu', {'action': action});
                }
            }

            if (angular.isUndefined($attrs.searchFn)) {
                $scope.searchFn = function () {
                    $scope.$emit('nav.search.execute');
                }
            }

            $scope.trustedBrand = angular.isDefined($attrs.brand) ? $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.brand) : $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.defaults.brand);
            $scope.hasMenus = function () {
                return angular.isDefined($scope.menus);
            }

            $scope.hasDropdownMenu = function (menu) {
                return (angular.isDefined(menu.menu) && angular.isArray(menu.menu));
            }

            $scope.isDivider = function (item) {
                return (angular.isDefined(item.divider) && angular.equals(item.divider, true));
            }

            $scope.navAction = function (action) {
                $scope.navFn({'action': action});
            }
        },
        template: 
        '<nav class="navbar" ng-class="{\'navbar-inverse\': inverse,\'navbar-default\': !inverse,\'navbar-fixed-top\': affixed == \'top\',\'navbar-fixed-bottom\': affixed == \'bottom\'}" role="navigation">' +
            '<div class="container-fluid">' +
                '<div class="navbar-header">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">' +
                        '<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<a class="navbar-brand" ng-bind-html="trustedBrand"></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div collapse="isCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse">' +
                    '<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-if="hasMenus()">' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="menu in menus" dropdown>' +
                            '<a ng-if="!hasDropdownMenu(menu)" ng-click="navAction(menu.action)">{{menu.title}}</a>' +
                            '<a ng-if="hasDropdownMenu(menu)" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>' +
                                '{{menu.title}} <b class="caret"></b>' +
                            '</a>' +
                            '<ul ng-if="hasDropdownMenu(menu)" class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                '<li ng-repeat="item in menu.menu" ng-class="{\'nav-divider\': isDivider(item)}">' +
                                    '<a ng-if="!isDivider(item)" ng-click="navAction(item.action)">{{item.title}}</a>' +
                                '</li>' +
                            '</ul>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '<form ng-if="search.show" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<div class="input-group">' +
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.terms" />' +
                                '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                                    '<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">' +
                                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>' +
                                    '</button>' +
                                '</span>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</form>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</nav>'
    };
});
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v2LMOU)

***For the Future***

I'm going to use this solution, but I'm not going to mark it as the solution. I figure if in the future someone comes up with a real solution then I can mark it as such.